# Cassandra consistency Issue

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We have our Cassandra cluster running on AWS EC2 with 4 nodes in the ring. We have face data inconsistency issue. We changed consistency level two while using "cqlsh" shell, the data inconsistency issue has been solved.

But we dont know "How to set consistency level on Cassandra cluster?"

Comment: Consistency is configured at client level, what client are you using to connect to cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

Consistency level can be set at per session or per statement basis. You will need to check the consistency level of writes and reads, to get a strong consistency your R + W ( read consistency + write consistency ) should be greater than your replication factor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java Driver, you can set default consistency at cluster level using "Cluster.Builder.withQueryOptions()" method.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#withQueryOptions-com.datastax.driver.core.QueryOptions-